# Inherit and then override parent init

Tags: python, class

I have the following code:

```
# file1.py
class GenericScript(object):

    def __init__(self):

        self.start_time = time.time()
        self.date_stem = str(timezone.now().date()).replace('-','')
        self.script_name = os.path.basename(sys.argv[0]).replace('.py','')
        self.file_name = None
        self.log_file = None
        self.integrity_field = '%s+%s' % (self.script_name, str(int(time.time())))


# file2.py
class RTUpdater(GenericScript):

    def __init__(self):

        self.integrity_field = '%s+%s' % (self.script_name, self.date_stem)
        self.update_title_data = False
        self.update_title_ranking = True
        self.update_title_box_office = True
        self.update_person_ranking = True
```

What I am trying to do is call `RTUpdate()` and get it to initialize all the items first in the parent Class and then add to those with its own `__init__` method. However, when I call it, the `self.integrity_field` keep raising an error because `self.script_name` is not defined, meaning it's not first inheriting the parent `__init__` variables. Here is how I'm calling it:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = RTUpdater()
    main(x)

>>> AttributeError: 'RTUpdater' object has no attribute 'script_name'
```

What am I doing wrong and how would I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to explicitly call the constructor of the parent class. Based on your inheritance of `object` I'm guessing you're using Python 2, so try this:

```
class RTUpdater(GenericScript):
    def __init__(self):
        super(RTUpdater, self).__init__()
        # ...
```

If you are actually using Python 3 you can just use `super().__init__()`.

Answer (score 1):

You completly override `__init__` as far as I see it. Just call `super().__init__()` in your inherited `__init__` (so that the init of the parent will be run) and check if the error still persists.

Or if you are using Python 2 you need to fix the classes for the super call: `super(RTUpdater, self).__init__()`.